# Taking specific data from .txt and sorting it into an excel or csv file through Python

Tags: python, data-science, export-to-excel

I am trying to write a program that will look through one folder which has 2 subfolders of .txt files and extract one line of data from each .txt file into an excel/CSV file with specific arrangements for the axis:

So for example, if I have 1 folder called '02202023' which is holding 2 subfolders, 'Control' and 'Experimental', which has let's say four .txt files in each of the data and within the files, it looks like this:

X      Y
399    230000
400    400000
401    500000

and I only want to take the line which has the '400' value of '400000' and put that into an excel sheet based on the time I took that data, let's say the file this came from is called '0second' since it is the initial timepoint, and there are additional files of '30second' '60second' '90second' in the folder(s).

I want to compile all the '400' data of all the .txt files into one excel on one sheet, that way I can have 'Control' in one column and 'Experimental' in the next column, leaving the left column to denote time timepoints so 'O' '30' '60' and title that column 'Time'. But I want to make sure it fills in the excel sheet correctly, so data from the '0second' file of 'control' and 'experimental' goes in the '0' row for their corresponding column 'control' and 'experimental'

**Quick Recap:**
parent folder: 02202023
subfolders with .txt files: Control, Experimental
File names in the subfolders: 0second, 30second, 60second, 90second
Data in the .txt file:

X      Y
399    230000
400    400000
401    500000

Desired data: Only the txt file data corresponding to the '400' line, so in the above would be ' 400000'
Output sheet: excel sheet which is templated with the following:
Time    Control    Experimental
0
30
60
90

**Desired output:** Extracting the '400' data from the .txt file and having it fill into the corresponding row of the file it came from.

So if the control 0second file, the '400' value was '400000' then the template would fill that in as so:
Time    Control    Experimental
0       400000
30
60
90

I have so far tried to follow some YouTube tutorial that describes pulling data from ONE folder which holds all the .txt files and compiling everything within that file into specific cells of excel. This is partially what I want except my issue is that I am trying to compile data from two folders into one excel sheet, and format only ONE data element from the .txt file into a specific cell of the sheet. So I am not sure how to change the tutorial advice for developing this program.

I also found some other stack overflow answers but they correspond to pulling a whole line from the txt file, I only want one part of a line.
Not sure if it would be easier to first pull all the lines to a CSV and then manipulate it from there instead?

So it would look like
0  '400' '400000'
30 '400' '390000'
60 '400' '380000'

Then I can tell the CSV file to take the specific cells and alter it further in another sheet to make the desired table, so have it "move cell A2 to sheet 2 B4" or something along those lines.

Comment: You should begin with easier tasks and maybe more basic tutorials to learn programming in Python.

Comment: I'm with @MichaelButscher, this is kind of a nuanced question, but if you show an earnest attempt to solve the problem, I will show you how I might solve it. If you want help getting started, my solution would use `pathlib.Path().rglob()`, the `csv` package and `dict.setdefault()`

Comment: Hey Alex, Are you still working on this?  If not let me know so I can move on with helping others.